# Getting value of another field from a different table? CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables, `departments` and `users`. On `users`, I have the following fields:

```
id | username | password | email | department | date_created
```

Now on `departments`, I have the following fields:

```
id | name
```

The `department` field on the `users` table is `INT` and it points to the corresponding `id` on the `departments` table. How do I retrieve the corresponding `name` to display on the `department` field when rendered on the web? I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));

        $departmentsArray = array();
        $departments = $this->Department->find('all');
        foreach ($departments as $department) {
            $departmentsArray[$department['Department']['id']] = $department['Department']['name'];
        }
        $this->set('departments', $departmentsArray);
    }

}
```

I am supposedly going to use it to retrieve the data on `View\Users\index.ctp`. However, it gives me an error:

```
Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: D:\server\root\app\Controller\UsersController.php 
Line: 11
```

Line 11 is `$departments = $this->Department->find('all');` from the first code block I gave above.

Sorry if this seems all too complicated, if there's a simpler way to approach this, please do tell me. I guess to put it simply, I need to retrieve data in a table via an id defined from another table.

**EDIT:**

Additional info from **Hyarion**, instead of using `find('all')` I used `find('list')` so I reduced the lines of code from 6 to 1! :) Here's the new code:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array('User', 'Department');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));

        $this->set('departments', $this->Department->find('list'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell your controller to load the model for Departments as well.  By default it is only loading Users.

Add this to the top of your controller:

```
var $uses = array('User', 'Department');
```

Comment: Oh nice! I didn't know that. Seems to work now. Thanks! Additional question, though not one of my concerns right now: is this the correct way to do it? Won't this approach bring performance slowdowns in the future if there are a lot of departments to load? Is there a more seamless way to do it?

Comment: It's the correct way to do it :)
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses
I'm not sure on performance, but I think it only actually uses the model if you call it.

Comment: Just as a note, I just looked at your loop, I'm not sure but I think you might want to try Model->find('list') instead of Model->find('all')

Comment: Okay, holy cow, I tried using `find('list')` and my code downsized to one line! :D `$this->set('departments', $this->Department->find('list'));` Thanks again!